# How To Sum and Create Pecentage Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sum, percentage

How To Sum And Create Percentage between 2 column ?
i use codeigniter and create in View Folder
this my code

```
<?php
$target= "SELECT SUM(a) FROM table_a WHERE a = '1'";
$total= "SELECT SUM(b) FROM table_a WHERE b= '1'";
$query = $this->db->select('concat(round('.$total.'/'.$target.')*100) as data_percentage');
echo $this->db->get()->row()->data_percentage;?>
?>
```

Please Help

Comment: Take a look at [this docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#query-builder-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a subquery like this :

```php
$query = "(SELECT IFNULL(SUM(`a`), 0) FROM table_a WHERE a='1') AS sum_a,
          (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(`b`), 0) FROM table_a WHERE b='1') AS sum_b,
          concat(round( (SELECT sum_b) / (SELECT sum_a) )*100) as data_percentage";
          $query = $this->db->select($query);
$result = $query->get('table_a');
echo $result->row()->data_percentage;
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, but i got error ```Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'sum_b' in 'field list' ```

Comment: I've updated my answer, (added another select subquery) since the aliases can't be used at the same level they are defined.